# Show that $B \setminus A \sim B$ where $A \subseteq B$ countable and $B \setminus A$ is infinite

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

Given $A\subseteq B$ such that $A$ is countable and $B\setminus A$ is infinite. I want to show that the cardinality of $B\setminus A$ is the same as the cardinality of $B$.

I know that since $B \setminus A$ is infinite, there is a function $g: \mathbb{N} \rightarrow B \setminus A$ injective. But how does this help me find a bijective function $f: B \setminus A \rightarrow B$ ?

Comment: Can you assume that any set can be well ordered?

Comment: $A$ is countable, which means it is bijective to a subset of $\Bbb N$. $g$ is also a bijection between $\Bbb N$ and $g(\Bbb N)$. So if you can think of a way to map the *disjoint* union of a subset of $\Bbb N$ and $\Bbb N$ to $\Bbb N$ bijectively, you have a ready-made bijection between $A\cup g(\Bbb N)$ and $g(\Bbb N)$.

Comment: Not really @Robert Shore

Comment: @Paul Sinclair If I understand what you say the idea is to find a mapping $h: C \cup \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ bijective where $C \subset \mathbb{N}$?

Comment: Almost. Note that I emphasized the **disjoint** union. You don't get to ignore that part. This turns the problem from being about sets of which you know almost nothing to a set which you've been studying since you were a child yourself, and for which a vast body of knowledge exists.

Comment: But if $C \in \mathbb{N}$ how come $C \cup \mathbb{N}$ can be disjoint? @Paul Sinclair

Comment: See [Disjoint union](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint_union). What is important here is that both sets can be treated as natural numbers, so that you can use whatever operations are handy to meet the challenge of fitting these together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $h: \Bbb N \to A$ be a bijection and denote $a_n=h(n)$.

Let $g: \Bbb N \to B \setminus A$ be an injection and denote $b_n=g(n)$.

$$\text{Define } f: B \to B \setminus A \text{ via }f(x)=
\begin{cases}
b_{2n}, & \text{if }x=a_n \\
b_{2n+1}, & \text{if } x=b_n \\
x & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$

Then $f$ is a bijection.